# Separation of Concerns, Dependency Inversion, and AutoMapper projections

Tags: mvvm, automapper, separation-of-concerns, dependency-inversion

Regarding to a MVVM project which applies AutoMapper.EF6 for projections, I have difficulty with separating the concerns of Data Access and view-models layers, and keeping the Dependency Inversion between these layer.

Supposing we have these layers and classes.

```
Models Layer: 
    Entity
    IEntityDA

ViewModel Layer:
    EntityVM
    EntityFormVM<TEntityVM, TEntity>

DataAccess Layer: 
    EntityDA: (Inherits from IEntityDA<TEntity>)
```

Now, in the `EntityFormVM`, I get an `IQueryable<TEntity>` from an `IEntityDA` instance, and project it into a list of `TEntityVM`, and finally call `IEntityDA.Dispose()`. In this way, the DA exposes an `IQueryable`!I don't know if it is right! and VM is responsible for disposing context since DA do not know when the work is finished!

On the other hand, I have some alternatives like inverting the dependency between DA and VM. Therefore, I will have `EntityDA<TEntityVM, TEntity>` which projects the results into `TEntityVM` and returns them. But, DA will depend on VM!

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

First, just recognize that `IQueryable` is a leaky abstraction. In order to effectively use it with whatever ORM you use, you'll need to use ORM-specific extensions.

My advice - don't worry about the layers here, you're going to want coupling vertically for a single request anyway across all those layers.

The concerns are already separated via those model objects. The rest is overkill.

Comment: About ORM-specific extensions, AutoMapper.EF6 is applied. Also, I forgot to mention that the VM here is responsible for disposing the context, since it manage the unit of work. And I guess all these are OK from your point of view, am I right?

Comment: If this is MVVM, is this part of a XAML-based app?

Comment: Yes, It is a XAML-based app.